# is parse push notification delay more than 2 minutes?

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification

I want to make an app that get push notification from server (iOS and android app). I'm interested in using `Parse`. I have heard in the past that parse push sometime delay up to 10 minutes or more. My app requires at most 2 minutes notification delay.

Can parse today do that job? or it still delay more than 2 minutes?

If it is delay more than 2 minutes what other solution you suggest me for push notification? I don't want difficult solution like making my own server or anything like that. I'm newbie please suggest me an easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Parse for my app. Yes, I still experience delays, sometimes longer than a few minutes. But most of time, it feels instantaneous. I would suggest something more realtime if you really care about the response time (go check out pubhub etc.). If you stick to use push notifications, there is always a chance that you will get delay.